# Configuring Named Arguments: inject value by the injected string variable's name

Tags: structuremap

[Passing Named Arguments](http://structuremap.github.io/resolving/passing-arguments-at-runtime/) explains how you can configure string value injection.

```
    container.With("color").EqualTo("Blue").GetInstance<IWidget>()
```

Allows me to specify the value of `color` to be `Blue` for any class, but it is effective only to the following `GetInstance()` call. The configuration does not stay with `container`.

Is there a way to configure the container to use certain value by the injected string variable's name? I have several classes that I want to inject certain value if it has `string color` on its constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out how to do this, but relying on variable name doesn't seem to be a good practice anyway and decided not to use this feature at all. More proper way would be [Options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-3.1), which also allows me to describe default value if any other container of the class did not specify values.